# How do I write an efficient Pair Matching algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking, tournament

I need help with an algorithm that efficiently groups people into pairs, and ensures that previous pairs are not repeated.

For example, say we have 10 candidates;

`candidates = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

And say we have a dictionary of previous matches such that each key-value pair i.e. `candidate:matches` represents a candidate and an array of candidates that they have been paired with so far;

`prev_matches = {0: [6, 5, 1, 2], 1: [4, 9, 0, 7], 2: [9, 8, 6, 0], 3: [5, 4, 8, 9], 4: [1, 3, 9, 6],  5: [3, 0, 7, 8], 6: [0, 7, 2, 4], 7: [8, 6, 5, 1], 8: [7, 2, 3, 5], 9: [2, 1, 4, 3]}`

So for `Candidate 0`, they were first paired with `Candidate 6`, and in the subsequent pairing rounds, they were paired with `Candidate 5`, `Candidate 1`, and `Candidate 2`. The same follows for the other key-value pairs in the dictionary.

There have already been four rounds of matches, as indicated by the length of all the matches in `prev_matches`. How do I script an algorithm that creates a fifth, sixth...nth(up to numberOfCandidates - 1) round of matches such that candidates do not have duplicate pairs?

So `Candidate 0` can no longer be paired with `Candidate 6`, `Candidate 5`, `Candidate 1`, and `Candidate 2`. And after a possible fifth round of matches, we could have our  `prev_matches` as such:

`prev_matches: {0: [6, 5, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 9, 0, 7, 2], 2: [9, 8, 6, 0, 1], 3: [5, 4, 8, 9, 0], 4: [1, 3, 9, 6, 7],  5: [3, 0, 7, 8, 9], 6: [0, 7, 2, 4, 8], 7: [8, 6, 5, 1, 4], 8: [7, 2, 3, 5, 8], 9: [2, 1, 4, 3, 5]}`.

**Here is a naive solution I tried:**

```
def make_match(prev_matches):
    paired_candidates = set()
    for candidate, matches in prev_matches.items():
        i = 0
        while i < 10:
            if i != candidate and i not in matches and i not in paired_candidates and candidate not in paired_candidates:
                prev_matches[candidate].append(i)
                prev_matches[i].append(candidate)
                paired_candidates.add(candidate)
                paired_candidates.add(i)
                break
            i += 1
    return prev_matches
```

It worked for the fifth round and returned the following:

`prev_matches = {0: [6, 5, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 9, 0, 7, 2], 2: [9, 8, 6 0, 1], 3: [5, 4, 8, 9, 0], 4: [1, 3, 9, 6, 5], 5: [3, 0, 7, 8, 4], 6: [0, 7, 2, 4, 8], 7: [8, 6, 5, 1, 9], 8: [7, 2, 3, 5, 6], 9: [2, 1, 4, 3, 7]}`

For the sixth round however, it failed to work as some candidates (7 and 8) couldn't find valid pairs:

`prev_matches = {0: [6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [4, 9, 0, 7, 2, 3], 2: [9, 8, 6, 0, 1, 5], 3: [5, 4, 8, 9, 0, 1], 4: [1, 3, 9, 6, 5, 0], 5: [3, 0, 7, 8, 4, 2], 6: [0, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9], 7: [8, 6, 5, 1, 9], 8: [7, 2, 3, 5, 6], 9: [2, 1, 4, 3, 7, 6]}`

As such, it's neither a reliable nor acceptable solution.

I'm considering treating it as a backtracking problem such that I'd explore all possible pairings across the rounds till I reach a wholly acceptable and valid solution after the nth round. But the concern here would be how to make it work efficiently.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: There're only 45 unique pairs in list with 10 items, so...

Comment: I'd start with this: `itertools.combinations(range(10), 2)`

Comment: @Woodford, .. which will return 45 (`10! / 2! * (10 - 2)!`) pairs which is definitely not enough to form even five unique pairs for each element.

Comment: Append the list of candidates to itself then use a sliding window with increasing width to pair the candidates

Comment: To clarify - someone other than you has already made the first four rounds of matches, and you are only in charge of the remaining rounds? Because there is a very simple solution if you are in charge of all rounds from the beginning.

Comment: Related questions: [Get n * k unique sets of 2 from list of length n in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64606498/3080723); [How to split a list into pairs in all possible ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020502/3080723)

Comment: Also probably useful: [networkx.max_weight_matching](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in charge of the tournament from the beginning, then the simplest solution is to organise the pairings according to a [round-robin tournament](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64606498/3080723).

If you have no control on the pairings of the first rounds, and must organise the following rounds, here is a solution using module networkx to compute a maximum matching in a graph:

```py
from networkx import Graph
from networkx.algorithms.matching import max_weight_matching, is_perfect_matching

def next_rounds(candidates, prev_matches):
    G = Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(candidates)
    G.add_edges_from((u,v) for u,p in prev_matches.items() for v in candidates.difference(p).difference({u}))
    m = max_weight_matching(G)
    while is_perfect_matching(G, m):
        yield m
        G.remove_edges_from(m)
        m = max_weight_matching(G)

for r in next_rounds({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
                     {0: [6, 5, 1, 2], 1: [4, 9, 0, 7], 2: [9, 8, 6, 0], 3: [5, 4, 8, 9], 4: [1, 3, 9, 6],  5: [3, 0, 7, 8], 6: [0, 7, 2, 4], 7: [8, 6, 5, 1], 8: [7, 2, 3, 5], 9: [2, 1, 4, 3]}):
    print(r)
```

Output:

```py
{(2, 7), (8, 1), (0, 9), (4, 5), (3, 6)}
{(2, 4), (3, 7), (8, 0), (9, 5), (1, 6)}
{(0, 7), (8, 4), (1, 5), (9, 6), (2, 3)}
{(9, 7), (0, 4), (8, 6), (2, 5), (1, 3)}
{(1, 2), (0, 3), (8, 9), (5, 6), (4, 7)}
```

Comment: thank you. Say I was in charge of all the rounds from the beginning as you asked in one of your comments, how would you propose I go about it?

Comment: @Wolemercy With a [round-robin tournament](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64606498/3080723)